# Disabled status of Angular reactive form controls not being applied to DOM correctly when form is switched?

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzxq2a

I have multiple `FormGroup` instances of the same control names. When the user selects a option, it switches from one set of data to another by changing the `FormGroup` that the UI is bound to. So in the template, it's `<form [formGroup]="form">`, but in the code I reassign this.form to be a different `FormGroup`. This seems to work fine and has done for months, even though I don't think I've seen it done like that before.

We've recently run into a problem where the enabled/disabled status doesn't seem to get applied to the DOM when the form is switched. So if we disable a few controls using `.disable()`, then switch from one form to another (in which they're still enabled), the HTML DOM elements on the page remain disabled. The data is correctly updated though. We've seen some unpredictable behaviour around this. Sometimes some get enabled, sometimes it's only the drop-downs that don't work. However, if we defer the disabling to a different event loop pass (with a `setTimeout`), then it usually works. So I think it's perhaps something to do with swapping out the form and needing to let Angular do its pass before en/disabling the controls. However, I would have expected that the enabled/disabled status of each control lives within each `FormGroup` in the first place, so just swapping out the form would be enough? This is certainly the case for the data.

I've built a simple example so you can see what I mean. Load it up, press the checkbox to switch off Active and see the text input and drop-down go to disabled. Press "Switch Form" to go to the different form and note that while the data in the form changes correctly, the disabled status does not, and remains as it was. If you use the "Switch Form With Timeout", you'll see that it works okay.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks.

Comment: as a note, stackblitz is great, but the **question itself** should hold a [mcve] (i.e relevant code included as code blocks). But short answer to your question. Forms are asynchronous, so this happens sometimes, and you need to wait a tick for all values to be correctly set.

Comment: Apologies, I did start trying to include the code but decided there was too much of it. I've also since realised that the link I posted just showed the app, not the code. I've changed it now.